# # Split data into training and test sets

Tags: python, machine-learning, regresión-lineal

```py
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
import io
dset = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['auto-mpg.csv']))

df = pd.read_csv('auto-mpg.csv')
df = df.dropna().drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
df.info()

df = df.rename(columns={'car name':'car_name'})
df.columns

df.info()

labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
df['car_name'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['car_name'])
df['horsepower'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['horsepower'])
df['displacement'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['displacement'])
df['acceleration'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['acceleration'])

df.isnull().sum()

dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[['car_name', 'horsepower', 'weight']])`
X = pd.concat([X_, dummies[['car_name', 'horsepower', 'weight']]], axis = 1)

df.info()

from sklearn.preprocessing import scale 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge, RidgeCV, Lasso, LassoCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

lin_mdl = LinearRegression()

x_train, x_test , y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.7, random_state=1)
```

y el error me da esto que me esta arrojando despues de ejecutar es este:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

lo que trato de trabajar son regresiones lineales, multiples y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Cierra el paréntesis

Comment: Ya, pero ahora me da este error
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Agrega el código completo por favor

Comment: Listo, ya agregue

Comment: En  ningún lugar veo tu variable `y` y `x`

Comment: Las define, pero aun así el error persiste

Comment: si quieres, podemos realiar un meet y le enseño, como va el funcionamiento del codigo que se trabajo en la clase sistemas inteligentes

Comment: Las cosas aquí no funcionan así, debes de colocar todo el código necesario para poder recrear tu problema